# Add a developer to my Facebook App

Tags: facebook, developer-tools

I created a new App at http://developers.facebook.com and I am trying to add friends as "Developers", but I get the following Error Message:

> param must be non-empty.

Comment: Are their names populating correctly in the typeahead search or are you just typing their name and pressing save?

Comment: Igy, I am also facing exactly same issue with no resolution. The field does not populate any name in the search box. I tried to put name as well as e-mail Id.

Answer (score 5):

Normally, you could only add a developer if they are your friend. However, if the account is a business account, you cannot add people as your friends to the account causing you to not be able to add them as developers to your app. The only reason for this is because it auto-populates names when you start typing into the box. Then you select from the list of names.

However, if you find out the developer's User ID, you do not need to add them as a friend.

Your user id should look something like:

`100000609876543` (<-- Not Mine)

If you're logged in to the account that you wish to find the ID of, you can find it by the default tool testing [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname). Or if you know what their facebook username is, you can find their User ID [here](http://findmyfacebookid.com/).

After that, simply type (or copy-paste) it into the field and it will take it as a value. I can confirm this works by doing it earlier today.

Comment: using the user id worked after trying everything else. thanks for posting!

Comment: You're welcome! This appears to be a more common problem than I thought, I hope more people benefit from this as well.
If anyone knows easier ways to get User IDs, please add that too.

Comment: to find quickly user id inspect the page and look for   "profile_id"

Answer (score 2):

You can indeed only add your facebook friends, and you must wait for the auto-complete search to find each user and click on the result.
Otherwise this may be a Facebook bug, there are so many in their dashboards...

Comment: It is able to add a developer if they are not your friend.