# Facebook Developer Console Error "Params must be non empty" while trying to add developer

Tags: facebook, android-facebook

I am trying to add a developer in Facebook developer console.
When I submit the developer E-maiId, it gives me an error message as "param must be non-empty. 
 Any suggestion to fix this?

Comment: Where do we *find the attached screenshot of the error message*?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't add a developer to my Facebook App. Help please](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21293385/cant-add-a-developer-to-my-facebook-app-help-please)

Answer (score 2):

As described here: [Add a developer to my Facebook App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21293385/cant-add-a-developer-to-my-facebook-app-help-please), you must be Facebook friends with the developer and wait for the Facebook system to show the friends' name when you start typing it.

Answer (score 2):

Well according to their documentation "Managing Development Cycles" in the "Test" section (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/bestpractice/managing-development-cycle/) it states,

"Users can be added by specifying their name (if they are your friend), email address or Facebook User ID. **Users are not required to be friends in order to be added to a Role.**" (emphasis mine)

That said, the reason I stumbled upon this SO is because I'm having the same exact problem. I'm beginning to suspect their documentation is out of date?